# why <nobr> does not work with Foundation widget?

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I hava a problem.

```
<nobr>
      <a href="#" class="button">Button 3</a>
      <ul class="button-group">
        <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nobr>
```

I want to display all Button in a row but  not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr):

> The HTML  element prevents a text from breaking into a new line
>   automagically, so it is displayed on one long line and scrolling might
>   be necessary. **This tag is not standard HTML and should not be used.
>   Instead use the CSS property white-space**.

Instead of `nobr` why not use `display: inline-block`:

```css
ul li,
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="button">Button 3</a>

<ul class="button-group">
  <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want all to be in the same line use `float: left`:

```css
ul li,
a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="button">Button 3</a>

<ul class="button-group">
  <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 1</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 2</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 3</a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because it isn't a standard tag, [MDN fills in a few more blanks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr). In terms of fixing your problem, make sure the list elements are set to "display:inline".